# Overloading typescript interface definition for $injector.get in angular1 project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I am working on migrating an angular1 project from javascript to typescript, and would like to add to the [overloaded $injector.get method](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts#L1856-L1892) to include the project's own injectable types. I read [this typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) on merging interfaces. I added this into an imported d.ts file:

```
import TrendDisplayService from 'services/TrendDisplayService';
declare namespace angular {
  export module ng.auto {
      export interface IInjectorService {
        get(name: 'trendDisplayService'): TrendDisplayService
      }
  }

}
```

However I am still seeing the "not assignable" type error when doing the following:

```
let trend:TrendDisplayService = $injector.get('trendDisplayService');
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the declaration module should be **auto** and not ng.auto.

```
declare namespace angular {
    export module auto {
        export interface IInjectorService {
            get(name: 'trendDisplayService'): TrendDisplayService
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh thanks for the correction. Unfortunately, this is still not working in my project, but I have a strong suspicion it is due to some tsconfig issue... should this work if I put your corrected snippet directly in the file where I am doing `let trend:TrendDisplayService = $injector.get('trendDisplayService');`? Or is this not allowed?

Comment: Yes, this will work. You can put this anywhere in your project.